# I have a nested map in Java, not getting how to put data in that map

Tags: collections

I am using a nested map something like this
Map>>> mapObj = new HashMap>>>

I am not getting how to put data in this map. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your code? Please show the actual declaration of your nested structure.

Answer (score 0):

All is referenced. you can directly navigate to the object and call put on to it. e.g-

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> student = new HashMap<>();
student.put("studentObject1", new HashMap<>());//initialize child object once.
student.get("studentObject1").put("name", "Aarti");//get reference of child object and put key value in it.
```